# How to set proxy for chrome browser in cypress

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, cypress

I want to set proxy only for chrome in cypress. Documentation says how to set proxy globally `set HTTP_PROXY=http://my-company-proxy.com` but I want to set only for chrome in some config file.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is no option to set proxy in cypress config file, only at operating system (Windows or Linux) as you already mention.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#View-proxy-settings-in-Cypress